# Arguments to a shell script from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I have a text file (Text.txt) having content as follows,

1. Name1 Text1
2. Name2
3. Name3 Text3

I want to write a shell script where i have to take Name1 , Name2 and Name3 as first arguments and Text1/Text3 as second argument .
Condition: My script should check each line if second argument is present.

My output should be displayed as follows :

1. Arg1: Name1 Arg2: Text1
2. Arg1: Name2 Arg2: *No args found*
3. Arg1: Name3 Arg2: Text3

I dont know where to start.
Can someone help me on .

Comment: Can you provide your desired output? What have you tried?

Comment: My output should be displayed as follows :

Arg1: Name1 Arg2: Text1
Arg1: Name2 Arg2: <No args found>
Arg1: Name3 Arg2: Text3

Comment: Kindly update your question with that info.

Answer (score 2):

Using `read` in an `while` loop:

```
while read -r cmd args; do
  printf "Arg1: %s Arg2: %s\n" "$cmd" "${args:-No args found}"
done < Text.txt
```

Bash Parameter expansion is used here with `${args:-No args found}` that set `$args` with `No args found` value is it's unset or null.

I removed the leading numbers as I'm not sure they are present in your text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following :

```
awk -F' ' '{ 
 printf $1" Arg1: "$2" Arg2: ";
 if(length($3)){
  print $3}
 else {
  print "No args found"}
 }' Text.txt
```

It prints the first two columns with your desired input, and checks for a third one (with the `if`) for the last output.

*EDIT* : If the line numbers (`1.`, `2.`, etc.) aren't part of the text file, update the command line to the following :

```
 awk -F' ' '{ 
  printf "Arg1: "$1" Arg2: ";
  if(length($2)){
   print $2}
  else {
   print "No args found"}
  }' Text.txt
```